# Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \operatorname{cosec}(2x)}{\cos(5x)}$

Tags: limits

I am having difficulties to find the limit for

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \operatorname{cosec}(2x)}{\cos(5x)}$$

I tried to get rid of $ \operatorname{cosec} $ fist

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\dfrac{x}{\sin(2x)}}{\cos(5x)}$$

Probably I should get it to a point where I could make use of $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ but I don't know how to continue.

Maybe if one could give me a hint for the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \csc(2x)}{\cos(5x)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x }{\sin2x\cos(5x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}\frac{1}{2\cos(5x)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Excellent. After using mathlove's hint I got to this solution too.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{x\csc x}{\cos 2x}=\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\frac1{2\cos 5x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\cdot\frac12$$

Comment: Very nice, DonAntonio! +1

Answer (score 3):

HINT : You can use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}=1.$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This brought be to Adi's solution!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin (2x)\cos (5x)}$$
apply the formula $$\sin A\cos B=\frac{1}{2}(\sin (A+B)+\cos (A-B))$$
 $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x}{\sin (7x)-\sin (3x)}$$ 
further use L hospital to get the limit as $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor expansion of Csc[y] built around y=0 is 1/y + y/6. You may forget the denominator and arrive to x (1/(2x) + (x/3)) = 1/2